# Could someone please explain "Note: This method should be called under AWT tree lock."?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to make my program read the answers entered into a questionnaire-like form. For this purpose I plan to use `getComponents()` to get the answer fields I require (e.g. text fields, radio buttons, etc.), and then use methods like `getText()` to read the answers.

I have never used `getComponents()` and am just learning Java/Swing/AWT. The above warning in the documentation for `getComponents()` intimidates me, because I have no idea what a "tree lock" is, or where to find out what it is. Google has yielded nothing.

Even if `getComponents()` turns out to be an inappropriate solution to my problem, for the sake of learning I would still like my question answered.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Don't use `getComponents()` for this as you'll be building a fragile GUI that will break if anything is structurally changed later. Instead use standard OOP practices, including getter methods to allow other classes to be able to extract the state of key components.

Comment: The "tree lock" is meant to provide a safe guard for modifications to the UI itself (adding/removing components).  If you're running the code correctly in the Event Dispatching Thread, you shouldn't need it - Also, what Hovercraft said

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I see no problem with using `getComponents()`. It is a getter and therefore using standard OOP. The state of the application may be obscured or changed in any number of ways regardless of which getter or setter is used. OOP offers no help here. If you want a consistent view of the world you need to use pure functional programming (which means immutable data structures, too). See Clojure for a practical and reliable way to add mutability to such an application.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I was also curious about the inner workings of the `AWT tree lock` (`AWTTreeLock`/`TreeLock`) so I did some research which I will try to summarize here.

First of all bear in mind, that in *Swing* one should **only** access `Components` on the [AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (see [Swing's Threading Policy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html)). Therefore it is generally recommended to always prefere [SwingUtilities#invokeLater()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3551542/3270595) instead of `Component#getTreeLock()` for GUI synchronization tasks. If one can guarantee, that all access to the GUI components is done on the EDT, there should usually be no need to explicitly synchonize on `Component#getTreeLock()`.

According to David Holmes *AWT* was on the other hand originally [intended to be accessible by multiple threads](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2007-March/003762.html), which might also explain why the Javadoc of strict AWT classes (e.g. `Component` and `Container`) do not inclcude the thread-safety warning usually found in the Javadoc of Swing classes ("Swing is not thread safe..."). In this regard `Component#getTreeLock()` returns the `static final` lock Object shared by all AWT components. AWT classes synchronize on this object when modifying/accessing the component tree (e.g. during `Container#addImpl()`) and it is the client's responsibility to synchronize on this lock when multiple threads access the component tree. From this point of view `Component#getTreeLock()` seems to be a relict from this original AWT design and today mainly exists for backward compatibility and arguably for some border case uses like e.g. accessing components from multiple threads before the AWT event dispatch thread has started. On the other hand *additional* synchronization on the tree lock doesn't hurt either in some cases (I guess the small performance penalty can easily be neglected) - e.g. I'd still recommend tree lock synchronization during calls to `Container#getComponents()`, `Container#getComponentCount()` and `Container#getComponent(int)` (as documented in the Javadoc of these methods) and possibly also during layout operations in Java [LayoutManagers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html) (as suggested in the Javadoc of `Component#getTreeLock()` - actually these two rules are more or less the same, since most of the time `LayoutManagers` make use of exactly these three methods).

**Available documentation and information about the AWT tree lock**

It's a shame that a public Java API method intended for GUI thread synchronization is so poorly documented. Actually it seems the only "documentation" is provided by the Javadoc of `Component#getTreeLock()` itself, which might very well be listed as a good example for [bad practice getter documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1029126/3270595):

```
/**
 * Gets this component's locking object (the object that owns the thread
 * synchronization monitor) for AWT component-tree and layout
 * operations.
 * @return this component's locking object
 */
```

Other than that there are some hints about the intended usage of the tree lock in the documentation of `Container#getComponents()`, `Container#getComponentCount()` and `Container#getComponent(int)`.

```
Note: This method should be called under AWT tree lock.
```

and in the source code comments of some Java classes referencing `Component#getTreeLock()` like e.g. `java.swing.GroupLayout`:

```
public void invalidateLayout(Container parent) {
    checkParent(parent);
    // invalidateLayout is called from Container.invalidate, which
    // does NOT grab the treelock.  All other methods do.  To make sure
    // there aren't any possible threading problems we grab the tree lock
    // here.
    synchronized(parent.getTreeLock()) {
    [...]
```

One interesting detail here is, that Java `LayoutManagers` do most of the time synchronize on the tree lock when doing layout operations - e.g. in the methods `layoutContainer()`, `minimumLayoutSize()` and `preferredLayoutSize()` of `FlowLayout`, `BorderLayout` and `GridLayout`. But strangely enough this pattern is not consistently applied to all Java `LayoutManagers` - e.g. `GridBagLayout` does synchronize on the tree lock in the method `getLayoutInfo()` but does not do so in the method `arrangeGrid()`, although both methods access the component tree. `BoxLayout` on the other hand does not synchronize on the tree lock at all (see also [this thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1394084?start=0&tstart=0)). FWIW the Java tutorial for [Creating a Custom Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/custom.html) does not mention tree locks at all and the given example does not do any synchronization. Still, a lot of third party `LayoutManagers` also adhere to this synchronization pattern like e.g. JGoodies [FormLayout](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.jgoodies/forms/1.2.1/com/jgoodies/forms/layout/FormLayout.java) and the [Custom Layouts Blog](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-982637) says that

> Synchronizing on the object returned by the container's getTreeLock
>   method ensures thread safety while performing the layout

In my opinion this inconsistency and the lack of proper documentation is very confusing. E.g. I still have no idea under which circumstances it would absolutely be necessary for `LayoutManagers` to synchronize on the tree lock. I'd guess that normally (i.e. if component access stays on the EDT) synchronization should not be necessary. On the other hand this extra bit of synchronization certainly doesn't hurt either...

Also Java bug [JDK-6784816](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6784816) provides some information on the subject. It states that

> AWT tree lock is a public lock that should be used for any hiearchy or
>   layout operations *by developers*, not by AWT.

and that

> applications that call them [the methods `Container#getComponents()`, `Container#getComponentCount()` and `Container#getComponent(int)`] without AWT tree lock must realize that
>   they do this on their own risk. For example, due to some timings
>   changes, the methods may return incorrect values without proper
>   synchronization under AWT tree lock.

I would still strongly advice against solely relying on tree lock synchronization instead of synchronization on the EDT, considering the inconsistent synchronization on the tree lock that can be found in the Java API alone (not to mention possible third party API's). I'll conclude with [Thomas Hawtins words on this subject](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2007-March/003763.html):

> Swing is single threaded, AWT is not. However, AWT has thousands 
>   (literally) of threading bugs, which are unlikely to be fixed. It is 
>   unreasonable to expect multithreaded AWT application code not to be 
>   completely broken.

---

**Further references and links**

- [validateTree in Java 7.x doesnt work (in Java 6.x was fine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758069/validatetree-in-java-7-x-doesnt-work-in-java-6-x-was-fine/11392217#11392217)
- [System.exit is not thread-safe on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814367/system-exit-is-not-thread-safe-on-linux)
- [getTreeLock() thread on coderanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/346164/GUI/java/getTreeLock)
- [GetTreelock thread on codeguru](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?38633-GetTreelock)